# how to write two countries mobile number Regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to write China and Europe country phone number for regx. Here is China phone number validation.
 How can i validate when europe people enter europe country phone numbers using same this regx?
Thanks

```
personalPhone: [/^(\+86)-1[3|4|5|7|8]\d{9}$/, 'Please Enter Valid Phone Number!']
```

Comment: Can't you write two regx? `if(china_regx) {return true;} else if(europe_regx) {return true;} else {return false;}` If it passes one of the regx then it wil return true everything else is false.

Answer (score 0):

/(^+86-1[3|4|5|7|8]\d{9}$)|(^Europe$)/
like this 
(^+86-1[3|4|5|7|8]\d{9}$) match China country phone number
(^Europe$) match Europe ,I don't know the rules, so you need finish by youself;